# Javascript focus on browse button of file input

Tags: javascript, file, input, focus

I am trying to focus on the browse button of the file input control.

so I have something like

```
 <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" >
```

and in javascript I have

```
document.getElementById("upload").focus();
```

but the focus remain on the text field and comes to browse button only after i hit tab.
Is there a way that I could write a script to set the focus on the browse button?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you show a little more of code? The javascript seems to be Ok, but it depends when it is called if it will work. When do you want to call that javascript to change the focus (on page load, after writing 10 chars in the textbox...)?

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done. You have almost zero control over the constituent parts of a file upload field, partly for security reasons and partly because the standards do not define what constituent parts a file upload field might have. It is entirely possible the browser might render a file upload interface without any ‘Browse’ button.

Answer (score 2):

This question's been around for a while, allowing standards to evolve and develop with new functionality, but I've had success with the following code:

```
<input type="file" id="file_field" />

<input type="button" value="click me"
    onclick="document.getElementById('file_field').click()" />
```

I've managed to test it in Chrome and Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9 so far, and I suspect it would work in Firefox too. Hope this helps someone!