# How to focus input with type file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to focus input with type file, after user clicked on button, and input was shown. So i have this situation:

```
function TaskAttachments({ icon, label, taskId }) {
  const inputRef = useRef()

  const onInputShown = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus()
  }

  return (
    <TaskNavElement icon={icon} label={label} cbOnShow={onInputShown}>
      <input ref={inputRef} type="file" />
    </TaskNavElement>
  )
}
```

Notice, that `TaskNavElement` has a child, and when it's rendered it's triggering onInputShown, so I'm having correct inputRef.

But seems to using current.focus is not working. What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

So here is `TaskNavElement` code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Icon from '../../../../../../../components/UI/Icon/Icon'
import { usePopUp } from '../../../../../../../hooks/usePopUp'

function TaskNavElement({ icon, label, children, cbOnShow }) {
  const navElementRef = useRef()
  const containerRef = useRef()

  const [showPopUp] = usePopUp(navElementRef, containerRef, true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showPopUp) cbOnShow()
  }, [showPopUp])

  return (
    <li className="NavElements-Item">
      <div ref={navElementRef}>
        <Icon name={icon} size="12" helperClass="Item-Icon" />
        <span className="Item-Label">{label}</span>
      </div>
      {showPopUp && <div ref={containerRef}>{children}</div>}
    </li>
  )
}

export default TaskNavElement
```

I'm using this wrapper in case that I have this elements like a nav in some component, and on click on TaskNavElement I'm rendering a child, that's are a popups, but now I need to have ability to upload file, on `TaskNavElement` clicked.

Comment: please post the code for `TaskNavElement `, how are you triggering the `cbOnShow`

Comment: Just wanted to understand the context :- Why do you even need to do so? Is is just a matter of accessibility? or you want to have custom button for file?

Comment: Should you put the ref on ```TaskNavElement``` ??

Comment: seems cannot be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925811/javascript-focus-on-browse-button-of-file-input

Comment: check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-shockley-1k55h
click will trigger the file selection and focus will only focus it

Comment: i've provided an update on TaskNavElement code. please check this out!